Can at least one fixed point of a correspondence be approximated by fixed points of nearby continuous functions?
Let $X$ be a non-empty compact convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Let $\Gamma$ be a correspondence that maps from $X$ into $X$—meaning that for every $\in X$, $\Gamma(x)$ is a non-empty subset of $X$—such that

the graph of $\Gamma$, $\operatorname{Gr}(\Gamma)\equiv\{(x,y)\in X\times X\,|\,y\in\Gamma(x)\}$, is closed in $X\times X$; and
$\Gamma(x)$ is a convex subset of $X$ for every $x\in X$.

Suppose furthermore that $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ and $f$ are such that

$f_m:X\to X$ is continuous for each $m\in\mathbb N$;
$f:X\to X$ is such that $f(x)\in\Gamma(x)$ for every $x\in X$; and
$\lim_{m\to\infty}f_m(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in X$ pointwise.

For more details on the existence of such $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ and $f$, see this.
Let $K\equiv\{x\in X\,|\,x\in\Gamma(x)\}$ denote the set of fixed points of $\Gamma$; that $K$ is not empty follows from Kakutani’s fixed-point theorem. For each $m\in\mathbb N$, let $B_m\equiv\{x\in X\,|\,x=f_m(x)\}$ denote the set of fixed points of $f_m$; that $B_m$ is not empty follows from Brouwer’s fixed-point theorem. Define $$B\equiv\operatorname{closure}\left(\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb N}B_m\right).$$

CONJECTURE: The intersection of $K$ and $B$ is not empty: $K\cap B\neq\varnothing$.

In words: there is at least one fixed point of $\Gamma$ that is arbitrarily close to some fixed points of the functions $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$. This is plausible, given that $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ “converges into” $\Gamma$—albeit only pointwise (and not necessarily uniformly), so that elusive convergence behavior making the fixed points of $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ elope from the fixed points of $\Gamma$ is also plausible.
MY ATTEMPTS:

It is straightforward to come up with examples showing that the convex valuedness of $\Gamma$ is indispensable. Even if $K$ is not empty in such cases (which is no longer a guarantee without the assumption of convex valuedness), it can be bounded away from the points in $B$.
It is also easy to see that $K$ is not necessarily a subset of $B$. That is, not all fixed points of $\Gamma$ can be approximated by fixed points of $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$. The conjecture is quite weak, stating that at least one fixed point of $\Gamma$ can be thus approximated.
I have tried hard to come up with counterexamples that are rigged against the conjecture, but it has persisted against my attempts to disprove it. The hypotheses together seem to me to force $K$ to intersect $B$, which makes me suspect that the conjecture is true. The strength of this suspicion is moderate, mixed with skepticism.
I also sought to establish a positive result. I tried proving the conjecture via separating-hyperplane arguments, but I have kept hitting dead ends so far. The key seems to be to identify a fixed point of $\Gamma$ that is in some vague, to-be-operationalized sense “critical” and is forced to meet a “critical” accumulation point of the set of fixed points of $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The function $f$ can be discontinuos, right?

@AlexRavsky Yes, and sometimes you don’t even have a choice.

It seems I can prove the conjecture for $n=1$, so now I am studying its two-dimensional case.

There is the following counterexample for $n=2$. Let $X=[0,1]^2$ and $\Gamma(x)=\{(0,0)\}$ for each $x\in X$. Then $K=\{(0,0)\}$. For each natural $m$ define the map $f_m:X\to X$ as follows. Put $F_1=[0,1]\times\{1/m\}$, and $$F_2=[0,1]\times\{x_2\in [0,1]:|x_2-1/m|\ge 1/(2m)\}.$$ Define a function $\varphi:F_1\cup F_2\to [0,1]$ such that $\varphi(x_1,1/m)=x_1/2+1/2$ for each $x_1\in [0,1]$ and $\varphi(x)=0$ for each $x\in F_2$. Since $\varphi$ is a continuous function from a closed subspace $F_1\cup F_2$ of a normal space $X$, by the Tietze-Urysohn theorem $\varphi$ can be extended to a continuous function $\bar\varphi:X\to [0,1]$. Now for each $x\in X$ put $f_m(x)=(\bar\varphi(x),1/m)$. It is easy to see that for each $x\in X$ when $m$ tends to the infinity then we eventually have $f_m(x)=(0,1/m)\to (0,0)\in\Gamma(x)$. Moreover, for each natural $m$ we have $B_m=\{(1,1/m)\}$, so $K\cap B=\varnothing$.
On the other hand, we can prove the conjecture for $n=1$ as follows.
The set $A=\operatorname{Gr}(\Gamma)\cap\{(x,x):x\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times X$ as an intersection of two closed sets, so $A$ is compact. The set $K$ is compact too, being the projection of the set $A$ onto the first coordinate.
There exist real numbers $a<b$ such that $X=[a,b]$. Let $$y'=\sup\{y\in X: \forall x\in [a,y]\, \exists z\in \Gamma(x)\, z\ge x\}.$$ Suppose that $y'<b$. By the maximality of $y'$, there exists a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of points of $(y',b]$ convergent to $y'$ such that for each natural $n$ and each $z\in\Gamma(y_n)$ we have $z<y_n$, so, in particular, $f(y_n)<y_n$. Since the set $X$ is compact, the sequence $(f(y_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a cluster point, say, $z'$. Clearly, $z'\le \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=y'$. Since the graph $\operatorname{Gr} (\Gamma)$ is closed, $(y',z')\in \operatorname{Gr} (\Gamma)$, that is $z'\in \Gamma(y')$. On the other hand, there exists $z\in \Gamma(y')$ such that $z\ge y'$. Since the set $\Gamma(y')$ is convex, $y'\in\Gamma(y')$ and so $y'\in K$. Let $x'=\inf\{x\in X: [x,y']\subset K\}$. Since the set $K$ is closed, $x'\in K$.
Suppose first that $x'=a$. Then we suppose that $f_m(x')>x'$ for each natural $m$, because otherwise $x'\in K\cap B_m\subset K\cap B\ne\varnothing$. Put $x_n=x'$ for each natural number $n$.
Suppose now that $x'>a$. By the minimality of $x'$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of points of $[a,x')$ convergent to $x'$ such that for each natural $n$ and each $z\in\Gamma(x_n)$ we have $z>x_n$, so, in particular, $f(x_n)>x_n$. Since the sequence $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ converges to the function $f$ pointwise, there exists a strictly increasing sequence of indices $(m_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $f_{m_n}(y_n)-y_n<0$ and $f_{m_n}(x_n)-x_n>0$. Since the function $f_{m_n}(x)-x$ is continuous, there exists $t_n\in (x_n,y_n)$ such that $f_{m_n}(t_n)-t_n=0$. All points of the sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ belong to the compact set $B$. So the set $C$ of cluster points of the sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a nonempty subset of $B$. It is easy to see that any point $t\in C$ belongs to $[x',y']\subset K$, so $B\cap K$ is nonempty.
Suppose now that $y'=b$ and put
$$x''=\inf\{x\in X: \forall y\in [x,b]\, \exists z\in \Gamma(y)\, z\le y\}.$$ If $x''>a$ then similarly to the previous we can show that $B\cap K$ is nonempty. Finally, if $x''=a$ then the convexity of the values of $\Gamma$ implies that $K=[a,b]=X$, so $B\cap K=B$ is nonempty too.

Thank you so much, @AlexRavsky, for your ingenious answer! This is exactly the kind of two-dimensional counterexample I was looking for. Since I doubt a different, significantly higher-quality answer can be expected, I’m conditionally awarding the bounty to you. Before finalizing this, I would be grateful if you could provide some details about your positive proof for the one-dimensional case.

Upon reflection, I realized it was unfair of me to insist that you publish your affirmative proof for the $n=1$ case before being awarded the bounty, since the presentation of a counterexample had already satisfied the posted conditions. So, without further ado, the bounty is yours—you’ve earned it, and I’m extremely grateful to you for the amazing counterexample! At the same time, I’ve posted my own proof for the one-dimensional case. In case you’re interested, I would very much appreciate your feedback on it. Thanks again!

@triple_sec Oops, I am very sorry for the delay with the proof. I started to write it but noticed your answer. So now I am going to finish my proof first and then to look at your answer.

@triple_sec Inspired, I found a new, simpler and shorter proof, see the updated answer.

Great proof, thank you! It strikes me as somewhat similar in spirit to mine, albeit yours is terser because you appear to merge multiple cases more efficiently. Just one minor quibble: I edited your answer slightly because I wasn’t comfortable with how your threshold index $M$ for the convergence of $(f_m){m\in\mathbb N}$ did not depend on the indices of the sequences $(x_n,y_n){n\in\mathbb N}$—note that the function sequence converges pointwise, and not necessarily uniformly! I wonder if you agree with my proposed changes.

On reflection, I realized that your original argument does make sense if you treat the index $n$ corresponding to $x_n$ and $y_n$ as fixed momentarily. If you prefer to revert to your original answer, I would just suggest replacing $M$ with $M_n$ to emphasize this.

Alex Ravsky has already presented an excellent counterexample for $n=2$ and indicated that the conjecture is true for $n=1$. I’m now presenting my own proof for the latter case.
In fact, I’m going to prove something slightly stronger. Let $C$ be the set of those points in $x\in X$ for which there exists a sequence $(x_{\ell})_{\ell\in\mathbb N}$ in $X$ and a strictly increasing sequence $(m_{\ell})_{\ell\in\mathbb N}$ of positive whole index numbers such that $\lim_{\ell\to\infty}x_{\ell}=x$ and $x_{\ell}=f_{m_{\ell}}(x_{\ell})$ for each $\ell\in\mathbb N$. It is easy to see that $C\subseteq B$ (and a diagonal argument shows that $C$ is, in fact, closed). Therefore, if I show that $K\cap C\neq\varnothing$, then I will have proved the conjecture.
If $n=1$, then $X$ either consists of a single point or is a non-degenerate compact interval. The point case is trivial, so I’m going to focus on the case in which $X=[a,b]$, where $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Since $\Gamma$ has a closed graph and is convex valued, it must be the case that $\Gamma(x)=[L(x),U(x)]$, where $a\leq L(x)\leq U(x)\leq b$ for every $x\in[a,b]$. I’m going to call a point $x\in[a,b]$

“overwhelming” if $x<L(x)$; and
“underwhelming” if $U(x)<x$.

Intuitively, an overwhelming/underwhelming point sends its image strictly above/below the diagonal, respectively.
Case 1: There exist both overwhelming and underwhelming points.
Suppose that $U(x')<x'$ and $x''<L(x'')$. Without loss of generality, assume that $x'<x''$. Define
\begin{align*}
\underline w&\equiv\sup\{w\in[x',x'']\,|\,U(w)<w\},\\
\overline w&\equiv\inf\{w\in[\underline w,x'']\,|\,w<L(w)\}.
\end{align*}
The closed-graph property implies that $x'<\underline w\leq\overline w<x''$. Note that the definitions of $\underline w$ and $\overline w$ and the closed-graph property again imply that if $x\in[\underline w,\overline w]$, then $L(x)\leq x\leq U(x)$, which means that $[\underline w,\overline w]\subseteq K$. (Note: It is possible that $\underline w=\overline w$.)
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be so small that $x'<\underline w-\varepsilon<\overline w+\varepsilon<x''$. Using the definitions of $\underline w$ and $\overline w$, one can find for each $\ell\in\mathbb N$ some $w'_{\ell}$ and $w''_{\ell}$ such that

$\underline w-\varepsilon/\ell<w'_{\ell}\leq\underline w$;
$U(w'_{\ell})<w'_{\ell}$;
$\overline w\leq w''_{\ell}<\overline w+\varepsilon/\ell$; and
$w''_{\ell}<L(w''_{\ell})$.

In turn, using the pointwise convergence of $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ to $f$ (whose graph is included in that of $\Gamma$), one can find a strictly increasing sequence $(m_{\ell})_{\ell\in\mathbb N}$ of positive integers such that for each $\ell\in\mathbb N$,

$f_{m_{\ell}}(w'_{\ell})<w'_{\ell}$; and
$f_{m_{\ell}}(w''_{\ell})>w''_{\ell}$.

By the intermediate-value theorem, there exists some $x_{\ell}\in(w'_{\ell},w''_{\ell})$ such that $f_{m_{\ell}}(x_{\ell})=x_{\ell}$. By passing to a subsequence if necessary, it is without loss of generality to assume that $(x_{\ell})_{\ell\in\mathbb N}$ converges. The limit is in $C$ by this set’s definition, and it is also in $[\underline w,\overline w]\subseteq K$ by construction. Therefore, $K\cap C\neq\varnothing$.
Case 2: Either there exist no overwhelming points, or there exist no underwhelming points.
Without loss of generality, assume that there exist no overwhelming points. That is, $L(x)\leq x$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. If there exist no underwhelming points, either, then $K=[a,b]$ and the claim readily follows. Otherwise, if there do exist underwhelming points, let $$\widetilde w\equiv\inf\{w\in[a,b]\,|\,U(w)<w\}$$ be the infimum of the set of underwhelming points. The definition of $\widetilde w$, the closed-graph property, and the non-existence of overwhelming points imply that $[a,\widetilde w]\subseteq K$. (Note: It is possible that $\widetilde w=a$.)
Note that the existence of underwhelming points and the closed-graph property imply also that $\widetilde w<b$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be so small that $\widetilde w+\varepsilon<b$. Find for each $\ell\in\mathbb N$ some $\widetilde w_{\ell}$ such that

$\widetilde w\leq\widetilde w_{\ell}<\widetilde w+\varepsilon/\ell$; and
$U(\widetilde w_{\ell})<\widetilde w_{\ell}$.

In turn, find a strictly increasing sequence $(m_{\ell})_{\ell\in\mathbb N}$ of positive integers such that for each $\ell\in\mathbb N$, $f_{m_{\ell}}(\widetilde w_{\ell})<\widetilde w_{\ell}$; note that $f_{m_{\ell}}(a)\geq a$ is automatically satisfied. Therefore, there exists some $x_{\ell}\in[a,\widetilde w_{\ell})$ such that $x_{\ell}=f_{m_{\ell}}(x_{\ell})$. By passing to a subsequence if necessary, one can assume the convergence of $(x_{\ell})_{\ell\in\mathbb N}$ to some $x\in C$. In addition, $x\in[a,\widetilde w]\subseteq K$, and the proof is done.

I checked your proof and I think it is correct (but both claims "Without loss of generality...", which should be carefully checked because of possible asymmetry issues). Congratulation, a good job! You proof looks shorter than an expected rigorous presentation of my first proof, but longer than my second proof, where I found a trick to unite two cases to consider into one.

@AlexRavsky Good point. I usually don’t like to cut corners, but this answer was going to become too long as it is. I carefully double checked those instances of Case 1 in which the overwhelming point lies below the underwhelming point, and those instances of Case 2 in which there are no underwhelming points. I also verified that the passing-to-a-subsequence-if-necessary arguments do go through. Thank you so much for all your valuable input! It’s been fun to think and work together with you on this challenging problem!
